# cucumber test, jhipster and oauth: ClientRegistrationRepository bean not found

Tags: spring-security, oauth, cucumber, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

I have a problem with running Cucumber tests in a khipster project (I can reproduce it with jhipster as well) when I configure it to use oauth2.

I create the project with the following configuration file (I call it *mono.jdl*):

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType monolith
    authenticationType oauth2
    baseName helloworld
    buildTool maven
    packageName com.example.helloworld
    testFrameworks [cucumber]
  }
  entities *
}
```

I generate the project with a command: `khipster import-jdl mono.jdl`.

I create a very simple Cucumber test. I create a feature file (*src/test/features/kuku/kuku.feature*):

```
Feature: just a test

    Scenario: my scenario
        And one two three
```

and a file with steps (*src/test/kotlin/com/example/helloworld/cucumber/stepdefs/KukuStepDefs.kt*):

```
package com.example.helloworld.cucumber.stepdefs

import io.cucumber.java.en.When

class KukuStepDefs : StepDefs() {

    @When("one two three")
    fun magic() {
        println("four five six")
    }
}
```

I try to run the integration test with a command `./mvnw integration-test`. However, it fails with a following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.helloworld.web.rest.LogoutResource required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' in 'OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration' not loaded because OAuth2 Clients Configured Condition registered clients is not available


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to find *CucumberContextConfiguration* class. It contains such annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [HelloworldApp::class])
```

We must change it to:

```
import com.example.helloworld.config.TestSecurityConfiguration
(...)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [HelloworldApp::class, TestSecurityConfiguration::class])
```